# plotting a default equation involving trigonometric functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot the following;

```
syms x 
ezplot(tan(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2./tan(x+asin(sin./1.307).^2./sin(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2.*sin(x+asin(sin(x)./1.307)).^2), [0.349,1.396])
```

And I get the following error

```
Error using sin
Not enough input arguments.
```

I can't seem to find where I'm making a mistake, and it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `(x)`, or something similar, where I have put `XXXXXXX` below:

```
ezplot(tan(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2./tan(x+asin(sin XXXXXXX ./1.307).^2./sin(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2.*sin(x+asin(sin(x)./1.307)).^2), [0.349,1.396])
```

Comment: Ouch, I missed that but now I get, "Error using sym/tan
Too many input arguments."

Comment: ">> ezplot(tan(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2./tan(x+asin(sin(x./1.307))).^2./sin(x-asin(x./1.307)).^2.*sin(x+asin(sin(x)./1.307)).^2, [0.349,1.396])" fixed my problem thank you